# Increase sidebar width or alternative

Tags: google-maps, google-apps-script, google-sheets, sidebar

I'm trying to show a google maps widget into my sidebar via Script. But since the new version of Google Spreadsheets it seems that we can't choose the width of our sidebar anymore.

Is there a way to force it? Or an alternative in UiInstance to show something like this :
[image]

Regards,
Rave

Answer (score 1):

No. The sidebar width is set by Google and can no longer be changed.

From the release notes from Feb 25, 2014:

> In Google Docs and Forms, sidebars now ignore the setWidth() method;
>   they cannot be changed from the default width of 300px. This change
>   was applied to the new version of Sheets in the previous week's
>   release.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/releases/#february_2014

Comment: OK, mais est-il une autre manière (avec une interface flottante, ou autre) pour obtenir le même effet visuel?

Comment: Oui, tu peux créer une interface flottante de la grosseur que tu veux. Dialogs open in the center of the page.  https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs